# Delegate not get called

Tags: swift, mvvm, delegates

```
protocol WeatherManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateWeater(weather: ConsolidatedWeather)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}
```

ViewController: where i am setting value `didSelectRowAt` and using `performSegue` going to another `viewController`

```
   class WeatherListViewController: UIViewController {
            var delegate: WeatherManagerDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let index = weatherViewModel.didSelect(at: indexPath.row)
            self.delegate?.didUpdateWeater(weather: index)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: K.DetailsView.segueIndentifier, sender: self)
        }
        
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let destinationVc = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            
        }
    
    }
```

this is my ViewModel calss: from my ViewModel, I will send value to `ViewController` and Update `UI`

```
class DetailsWeatherViewModel{
    
    var  w = WeatherListViewController()
    
    func a(){
        print("aaa")
        w.delegate = self
    }
}


extension DetailsWeatherViewModel: WeatherManagerDelegate{
    func didUpdateWeater(weather: ConsolidatedWeather) {
        weatherData = weather
        print("weatherData: \(String(describing: weatherData))")
    }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

what I am doing wrong...????

Comment: How are you presenting `WeatherListViewController`?

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: Sorry, where are you presenting `WeatherListViewController`? Can you show the code for it/

Comment: Let's start debugging: `self.delegate?.didUpdateWeater(weather: index)` that's the line where you expect result, no? Let's see first, is `delegate` nil? If so, let's find ou why. Now, I think that your issue is because you are doing `var  w = WeatherListViewController()` which is creating a NEW instance, not the one you might be seeing on screen. Also, it's creating a new instance not connected to its Storyboard, so you'd fail on performSegue, it should crash on trying to access its IBOutlets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful of memory leaks when using delegate pattern. I think you can solve this problem by making protocol limit to `class` and declare property by `weak var`. Although WeatherListViewController disappeared, WeatherListViewController and DetailsWeatherViewModel are not likely to be deinit unless you use weak reference. Try this.

```
protocol WeatherManagerDelegate : class {
    func didUpdateWeater(weather: ConsolidatedWeather)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}
```

```
weak var delegate: WeatherManagerDelegate?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following MVVM architecture then you can create a viewModel object inside your viewcontroller and then use the updated values in VM directly using VM object.
Else if you want to use delegate then you need to write the protocols in viewModel and use it in VC. You shouldn't be creating Viewcontroller object inside the Viewmodel.